# Increase smoothness of video

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to create a python code that scans the barcode and retrieves the output. A library called **pyzbar** had already been created for the same purpose. Using that and OpenCV, I had created a code (attached below), for scanning and drawing bounding boxes on the barcode/QR code. The problem I'm facing is that when I input a pre-recorded video above 100 MB as input the output video that is displayed/saved is very slow, but with live stream, there is no such issue. I tried several methods to reduce the fps like **PROP_FPS**, but nothing worked. **I even tried multithreading method and it seems to not have any effect.** The code that I was referring to is attached below. Please help me out on the same.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
cv2.namedWindow("Result", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('2016_0806_040333_0081.mp4')
cap.set(3, 1280)
cap.set(4, 720)
#frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
#frame_height = int(cap.get(4))
#cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 0.1)
#size = (frame_width, frame_height)
#result = cv2.VideoWriter('processed_video.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'),0.1, size)
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    for barcode in decode(frame):
        myData = barcode.data.decode('utf-8')
        pts = np.array([barcode.polygon],np.int32)
        pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2))
        cv2.polylines(frame, [pts], True, (255,0,255),5)
        pts2 = barcode.rect
        akash = []
        akash.append(myData)
        cv2.putText(frame, myData, (pts2[0], pts2[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (255, 0, 255), 2)
"""        
        f=open('output.csv','a+')
        for ele in akash:
            f.write(ele+'\n')
"""
    result.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow('Result',frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
#video.release()
#result.release()
#cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print("The video was successfully saved")
```

Comment: "profile" your code to find out where time is spent. -- you can't *set* the width and height of a video file you are *reading*

Answer (score 0):

You could change the frame rate of your project, but this won't add missing frames. Even if your editor can attempt to extrapolate the needed frames, it can result in glitches.

Best approach if you have the option is to shoot the video at a higher frame rate to begin with.

Comment: The problem is that if I give a video of high fps i.e. higher size as well, the output video becomes very slow.